# Where can I find a step by step tutorial on how to setup primeminer and join a pool?

Tags: miner-configuration, primecoin

I'm new to Primeminer and couldn't find a tutorial on how to set it up. I have downloaded the Primeminer software and it seems to consist of only two files:

- a `.bat` file
- an `.exe` file.

Is that all there is?

Is primeminer universal for all cpu mining coins?

If you run primeminer and it connects to some pool, would the pool then send data back to your miner app, in order to crunch the data and send it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you are looking for this: http://www.peercointalk.org/index.php?topic=798.0

www.peercointalk.org - is a official forum of ppcoin and primecoin.

Short instruction for **Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander x64**:

```
# Update & upgrade repositories and install build tools
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential git

# Install xolominer dependencies
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libgmp-dev libboost-chrono1.54-dev libboost-filesystem1.54-dev libboost-system1.54-dev libboost-program-options1.54-dev libboost-thread1.54-dev

# Get db4.8 source, compile and install
wget http://download.oracle.com/berkeley-db/db-4.8.30.NC.tar.gz
tar -xzvf db-4.8.30.NC.tar.gz
cd db-4.8.30.NC/build_unix
../dist/configure --enable-cxx
make
sudo make install

# Tell your system where to find db4.8
export BDB_INCLUDE_PATH="/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/include"
export BDB_LIB_PATH="/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/lib"
sudo ln -s /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/lib/libdb-4.8.so /usr/lib/libdb-4.8.so
sudo ln -s /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/lib/libdb_cxx-4.8.so /usr/lib/libdb_cxx-4.8.so

# Pull the xolominer source from github
cd
git clone https://github.com/thbaumbach/primecoin.git xolominer

# Go to source and compile the code
cd xolominer/src
make -f makefile.unix
# Start mining
./primeminer -pooluser=[xpm-payout-address] -poolip=[choose-your-server] -poolport=1337 -genproclimit=[threads-to-use] -poolpassword=[some-random-password-for-protection]
```

Comment: how about windows

Comment: Do you familiar with cygwin? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin